# No genera csv en columnas SQL EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apartir de una query SQL con 3 columnas, creo un csv pero no me coloca nombre de las columnas en el csv y en el archivo solo se crea una columna.

¿Cómo puedo colocar el nombre de columna y separar mis campos del select en columnas?

Esta es la forma como creo mi archivo

```
DECLARE @ExportSQL nvarchar(max); 
SET @ExportSQL = N'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "select a.id_CUENTA,a.RFC_RECEPTOR,a.RECEPTOR 
from [factura] a left join [cuenta] b on  a.id_cuenta=b.id_CUENTA 
left join [PRODUCCION].[CLIENTE_DIRECCION] c on b.id_CLIENTE=c.id_CLIENTE 
where a.id_FACTURA_SITUACION IN (4)  
AND b.id_Regimen is null 
AND a.SERIE=''''AAA''''" queryout "' + @OutputFilePath + '\OutputData1.csv" -T -c -t -S QAS'''
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes, tienes 2 problemas que en realidad uno no es problema.

En primer lugar, sí está generando las columnas, pero las está separando por tabulador (la opción por default) y Excel no lo reconoce como tal por default. Para cambiarlo, solo necesitas agregar el separador que quieras usar después del parámetro `-t`. Probé usando una coma `-t,` y Excel lo reconoció sin problemas. Es importante aclarar que usar comas sin un archivo de formato puede generar información incorrecta si hay comas en los valores que se exportan. Con un archivo de formato, puedes agregar comillas a las cadenas de caracteres para evitar este problema.

En segundo lugar, está la opción de incluir los nombres de columnas. Desgraciadamente, la utilidad bcp no tiene esta opción y para incluirlos es necesario hacerlo de forma manual.

```
DECLARE @ExportSQL nvarchar(max),
        @Query     nvarchar(max),
        @OutputFilePath nvarchar(max) = 'C:\work'; 

SET @Query = N'SELECT ''''id_CUENTA'''',''''RFC_RECEPTOR'''',''''RECEPTOR'''' UNION ALL '
           + N'select CAST( a.id_CUENTA as varchar(20)), ' 
                  + N'a.RFC_RECEPTOR,' 
                  + N'a.RECEPTOR ' 
           + N'from [factura] a ' 
           + N'left join [cuenta] b on  a.id_cuenta=b.id_CUENTA ' 
           + N'left join [PRODUCCION].[CLIENTE_DIRECCION] c on b.id_CLIENTE=c.id_CLIENTE ' 
           + N'where a.id_FACTURA_SITUACION IN (4)  ' 
           + N'AND b.id_Regimen is null ' 
           + N'AND a.SERIE=''''AAA''''';

SET @ExportSQL = N'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "' + @Query  + '"'
               + ' queryout "' + @OutputFilePath + '\OutputData1.csv" -T -c -t, -S QAS ''' ;
           
PRINT @ExportSQL;
--PRINT @Query
EXEC(@ExportSQL);
```

Aprovechando el ejemplo, te recuerdo que solo porque el código tenga que ser interpretado en una sola linea, no significa que no le puedas dar formato para facilitar su lectura y modificaciones.

Answer (score 2):

La solución más simple, pasa por hacer un conjunto y hacer una unión con las cabeceras de los datos.

```
DECLARE @ExportSQL nvarchar(max); SET @ExportSQL = N'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "Select ''id_Cuenta'',''RFC_RECEPTOR'',''RECEPTOR'' UNION ALL select a.id_CUENTA,a.RFC_RECEPTOR,a.RECEPTOR from [factura] a left join [cuenta] b on  a.id_cuenta=b.id_CUENTA left join [PRODUCCION].[CLIENTE_DIRECCION] c on b.id_CLIENTE=c.id_CLIENTE where a.id_FACTURA_SITUACION IN (4)  AND b.id_Regimen is null AND a.SERIE=''''AAA''''" queryout "' + @OutputFilePath + '\OutputData1.csv" -T -c -t -S QAS'''
```

En cuanto a las columnas, lo más simple es usar un delimitador concatenado a la salida.

```
DECLARE @ExportSQL nvarchar(max); SET @ExportSQL = N'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "Select Concat(''id_Cuenta'',''|'',''RFC_RECEPTOR'',''|'',''RECEPTOR'' UNION ALL select concat(a.id_CUENTA,''|'',a.RFC_RECEPTOR,''|'',a.RECEPTOR from [factura] a left join [cuenta] b on  a.id_cuenta=b.id_CUENTA left join [PRODUCCION].[CLIENTE_DIRECCION] c on b.id_CLIENTE=c.id_CLIENTE where a.id_FACTURA_SITUACION IN (4)  AND b.id_Regimen is null AND a.SERIE=''''AAA''''" queryout "' + @OutputFilePath + '\OutputData1.csv" -T -c -t -S QAS'''
```

Pero las columnas tienen que ser casteables implicitamente. O hacer un cast explicito.

[Exportar a csv el resultado de consultas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/01/exportar-a-archivos-el-resultado-de-consultas-sqlcmd/)